# Как получить список групп vkontakte?

Tags: вконтакте, java, vkontakte-api

Хочу получить список групп.
Где ошибка в этой строке?

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.groups().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID,"id"));
```

Comment: Что за язык, SDK?

Comment: java  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Значит проверьте, какое значение возвращает

    VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID,"id")


Сомневаюсь, что во втором параметре должен быть "id", скорее всего, второй параметр - id группы. Может быть, список id групп через запятую.

Какое SDK?

UPD: нашел в доках ВК под Андроид.


    2) Запрос с параметрами.
    VKRequest request =
        VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_IDS, "1,2"));

Отсюда и видно что к чему.

Answer (score 1):

```
  VKRequest request = new VKRequest("groups.get", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, " place"));
```